# Storing env variables on the server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unix, web-applications

I usually use `~/.bashrc` in my development machine for storing facebook/twitter/etc api-key for the rails app and obtain it like `ENV["KEY"]`.

Is there any good practice for storing those keys in production mode (say on VPS server)?

Comment: **[This](http://railsapps.github.com/rails-environment-variables.html)** was just posted to [HN](http://news.ycombinator.com) today; seems quite relevant here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ryan Bates from Railscasts did a great screencast on keeping tokens and passwords in a YAML file and out of your repo.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/85-yaml-configuration-revised

**update:** After reading your question, I'm not sure this is relevant since this applies more to your local development environment.